# Is it possible to iterate over a specified range rather than the whole array in Angular (12+)

Tags: angular

I have an array, say `bars` on a `foo` property.

In my HTML template I can, of course, do

```
<div *ngFor="let bar of foo.bars">
  <!-- do something with bar -->
</div>
```

But, I want to treat my first `bar` differently, and then iterate over the second onwards.

What is the Angular equivalent of, say, something like

```
<div *ngFor="let bar of foo.bars[1..]">
  <!-- do something with bar -->
</div>
```

or, even

```
<div *ngFor="let bar of foo.bars[1..10]">
  <!-- do something with bar -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to go for this is to use the [slice pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe)

```
<div *ngFor="let bar of foo.bars | slice:0:10 )">
  <!-- do something with bar -->
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. I like that. And the `end` is optional. Perfect

Comment: You can also use [slice pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe)